# Why my Stored Procedure for Delete part is not working?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a stored procedure for both Insertion and Delete purposes. My insertion is working properly but my Delete part is not working and there are no Errors. S.P executed successfully.

```
DECLARE
    @UserID uniqueidentifier= '71019eed-af17-41ad-bea6-c27b0c21ad7d',
    @CreatedBy varchar(100)= 'dhanil',
    @CreatedDate datetime= NULL,
    @UpdatedBy varchar(100)= NULL,
    @UpdatedDate datetime= NULL,
    @UserInProject nvarchar(max)= null,
    @UserNotInProject nvarchar(max)= '0300d340-e2e4-452d-b77b-49830271c9bb,03a54a90-b7fb-465e-b057-7b876e117264,0f64aa12-1fab-4846-98c0-1d4589575eb4,18c9e7a8-d39d-435a-8d6a-718774239337'

    declare @UserInValue uniqueidentifier=null,@UserNotInValue uniqueidentifier=null

IF(@UserInProject IS NOT NULL)  
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO PATS.UserInProject 
    SELECT NEWID(),@UserID,VALUE,@CreatedBy,@CreatedDate,NULL,NULL FROM STRING_SPLIT(@UserInProject,',')
END
ELSE IF(@UserInProject IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM PATS.UserInProject WHERE UserID=@UserID AND ProjectID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@UserNotInProject,','))
END
```

This is the procedure i written.
Here is the table where im inserted and also want to perform Delete

[image]

Comment: `@UserInProject IS NOT NULL` is always FALSE as you never assign anything to it?

Comment: An `ELSE IF` executes only when the previous `IF` does not. Your `IF`s have identical conditions (`@UserInProject IS NOT NULL`), so the second one will never execute - either because the previous one executed, or because it is false.

Comment: @AlexK. i wanted to do delete only if the list is contain value

Comment: @GSerg ohh thank you for your information

Comment: I don't understand when one if block executes then how it moves to another if block.  And if first if block skips then how with same condition second if block executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same condition in your `IF` and `ELSE IF` , Change  your `ELSE IF` to

```
ELSE IF(@UserInProject IS NULL)
```

Ideally, you don't need `ELSE IF`, it can be simply changed to `ELSE`

If you want to make sure that `@UserNotInProject` have values, you can change your conditions like following.

```
IF(@UserInProject IS NOT NULL)  
BEGIN       
    --INSERT
END
ELSE IF(@UserNotInProject IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 
    --DELETE
END
```

Comment: I have modified the answer to take care of @UserNotInProject also. You can have a look.

Comment: You did a typo i think :)

Comment: Ok let me try again

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code may works.

```
    DECLARE
        @UserID uniqueidentifier= '71019eed-af17-41ad-bea6-c27b0c21ad7d',
        @CreatedBy varchar(100)= 'dhanil',
        @CreatedDate datetime= NULL,
        @UpdatedBy varchar(100)= NULL,
        @UpdatedDate datetime= NULL,
        @UserInProject nvarchar(max)= null,
        @UserNotInProject nvarchar(max)= '0300d340-e2e4-452d-b77b-49830271c9bb,03a54a90-b7fb-465e-b057-7b876e117264,0f64aa12-1fab-4846-98c0-1d4589575eb4,18c9e7a8-d39d-435a-8d6a-718774239337'

        declare @UserInValue uniqueidentifier=null,@UserNotInValue uniqueidentifier=null

    IF(@UserInProject IS NOT NULL)  
    BEGIN       
        INSERT INTO PATS.UserInProject 
        SELECT NEWID(),@UserID,VALUE,@CreatedBy,@CreatedDate,NULL,NULL FROM STRING_SPLIT(@UserInProject,',')
        DELETE FROM PATS.UserInProject WHERE UserID=@UserID AND ProjectID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@UserNotInProject,','))
    END
```